# What is the time taken by Quicksort?

Tags: quicksort

If the minimum time taken by quicksort algorithm to sort 1000 elements is 100 seconds, what will be the minimum time taken by it to sort 100 elements?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that we don't know. The O(N log N) behaviour only describes the highest order part of the time dependency.

If we assume that the implementation we are looking at follows `time = k * N * log N` (that is, we assume that there are no lower order parts), then the answer would be:

100 * 100 / 1000 * log 100 / log 1000 = 20/3 or approx 6.7 seconds

Answer (score 0):

average time complexity of quick sort is O(n log n) (also best case). if it takes 100 sec for 1000 elements, and will take 6.7 sec for 100 elements.